# Razor page with dropdown in layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, razor-pages

I have a razor pages app that should be able to host a specific set of data per project a user is assigned to. The main function of the app is to manage all of the data of a single project. What i would like is a way somewhere on EACH page to select one of the (+/- 5) projects a user is assigned to simultaneously. And store this in a session property to be able to use it in all of the Get's....

My trouble is that i would normally think of a viewcomponent for things to display on each page, however because a viewcomponent does not receive POST's (the parent razor page does) i can not use a dropdown with a "change project" button.

The only thing i could come up with was a project-change page... A dropdown with JS onchange posting to a separate razor page where the change is handled. But it seems like there should be some razor component that can handle this (like a viewcomponent with POST possibilities or so). ANybody an idea?

Thanks,
Alexander

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the best solution. But I experienced this problem several months ago and what I did is the form inside the ViewComponent firing the parent's Controller

Comment: I saw that one fly by as well, but that would mean that on every page i have would need to capture that event in it's controller.

Comment: Or maybe you can consider using Partial View in spite of View Components?
here's some refference
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.1